# Displaying Double value with exact 2 decimal in jsp

Tags: java, algorithm, jstl

I faced this situation, I have to display prices which is a double for example $75.30, for which my back end code returns me $75.3. To show it in a classic dollar price way(super scripted decimal value), i split them into 2 and made it display. with below code.

```
    <c:if test="${not empty price }">
        <c:set var="displayPrice" value="${fn:split(price, '.')}" />
        <sup>$</sup>${displayPrice[0]}
        <sup>
           <f:formatNumber minIntegerDigits="2" value="${displayPrice[1]}"/>
        </sup>
    </c:if>
```

But in this case what happened is, 75.3 became 75.03 while displaying. so i modified the code like this.

```
<c:set var="decimalPrice" 
       value="${displayPrice[1]<10 ?displayPrice[1]*10:displayPrice[1]}" />
<f:formatNumber minIntegerDigits="2" value="${decimalPrice}"/>
```

this worked , but values like $45.03 also got displayed as $45.30.

Cant change the back end code, how can i achieve this with any tag libraries or minimal manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `pattern` attribute in format tag lib

```
<f:formatNumber type="number" pattern="0.00" value="${decimalPrice}"/>
```

pattern `0.00` will pad `0`s after decimal point if required, you can also use `#` in the pattern if nothing required to be padded

**EDIT -1**

Instead of splitting you could try below, to extract

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${decimalPrice}" maxFractionDigits="2" />
<fmt:formatNumber value="${decimalPrice}" maxIntegerDigits="0" />
```

Comment: but i need to split it, to show it as super script and sub script, this line of code just wont do.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out,

```
<f:formatNumber minFractionDigits="2" value="${price}" var="formattedPrice" />
```

formatted it before splitting. Did the trick.